# How should I reduce the computing time in pandas on Kaggle?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, garbage-collection, kaggle

I am working on 2019 Data Science Bowl.The training and testing data is taking a long time when I am using pandas to read it ,I want to reduce the time so that the machine can run the analysis efficiently.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly as py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True) 

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

%matplotlib inline
keep_cols = ['event_id', 'game_session', 'installation_id', 'event_count', 'event_code', 'title', 'game_time', 'type', 'world']
specs_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/data-science-bowl-2019/specs.csv')
train_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/data-science-bowl-2019/train.csv',usecols=keep_cols)
test_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/data-science-bowl-2019/test.csv')
train_labels_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/data-science-bowl-2019/train_labels.csv')
```

Comment: Can you include more information and some code samples? Have you timed your code and identified which parts specifically are causing bottlenecks?

Comment: Reading the file is taking too much time into dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `read_csv` method has a `chunksize` argument yields a certain number of rows as an iterator. This is useful for very large data sets where you can train on a smaller subset of the data iteratively.

More information on iterating through files is described in the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking).

Comment: in addition if you specify your dtypes before hand and your datetime formats this greatly speeds up reading in dataframes. have a read of this very useful https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/